# What are the minimum set of SSIS 2010 project files to store in source control

Tags: svn, version-control, ssis

We are using Tortoise SVN and store our SSIS projects there. Currently, the entire solution is stored, including \bin and \obj files. This contributes to SVN bloat!

Are \bin and \obj files necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely no need to add the bin and object subfolders to your version control system.

Let's look at what you get with a 2012+ SSIS project that uses the default, project deployment model. An empty integration services project will consist of 5 files.

ProjectName.database this is rubbish that stems from the project's SSAS roots but do commit it. It's 2k though so nothing to worry about from a storage perspective

ProjectName.dtproj this one is crucial as it contains the definition of all the packages and data about those packages (protection level, etc). Do not lose this one.

ProjectName.dtproj.user this will be recreated if lost/not committed but despite it being a "user" file, I prefer that it be shared across team members as it contains things like last deployed server data.

Package.dtsx obviously, this is important as it your work. I've seen arguments for storing these as binary since diff'ing the XML is painful at best. There is a free VS extension in [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) that allows for a SmartDiff. It's better than nothing but you'll still get "noise" in your comparisons that you can ignore (Version build) but at least the layout gunk is ignored

Project.params Do commit this as it contains any project level parameters. Even if you don't use project parameters, this file will be there.

Optionally, there may be .conmgr files. Commit those too as they are project level connection managers, are referenced in the .dtproj file and the project will be unhappy if they do not exist.

What's in obj and bin anyways?

The obj folder will contain a copy of all the packages in the project plus connection managers, parameters file and the project definition. The bin folder will take all of that and put it into a zip with the .ispac file extension.

Comment: Fantastic and thorough explanation, billinkc.  Thanks!